# Second argument is not working in command line argument

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2015, computer-vision

Giving command line argument using visual studio 2015, showing error on second argument. Code is below

```
// command line options
        printf("Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.\n");
        printf("  -i,  --input=PATH          set the path to the input image\n");
        printf("                               (*.jpg, *.png, etc.)\n");
        printf("  -o,  --output=PATH         set the path to the output image\n");
        printf("                               (*.jpg, *.png, etc.)\n");
```

Whenever i give the output path it shows error on it. `Invalid command line argument`. My Sequence is like E:\1.jpg D:\ in command line argument.

Edit :

Parsing code

```
// parse command line arguments
    arg = 2;

    while(arg < argc)
    {
        //
        if(0==strcmp("-u", argv[arg]) || 0==strcmp("--usepyr", argv[arg]))
        {
            usepyr = 1;
            ++arg;
        }
        else if(0==strcmp("-i", argv[arg]) || 0==strcmp("--input", argv[arg]))
        {
            if(arg+1 < argc)
            {
                //
                sscanf(argv[arg+1], "%s", input);
                arg = arg + 2;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("# missing argument after '%s'\n", argv[arg]);
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else if(0==strcmp("-o", argv[arg]) || 0==strcmp("--output", argv[arg]))
        {
            if(arg+1 < argc)
            {
                //
                sscanf(argv[arg+1], "%s", output);
                arg = arg + 2;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("# missing argument after '%s'\n", argv[arg]);
                return 1;
            }
        }
```

Trying to run and check the result of the sample code from [here](https://github.com/nenadmarkus/pico/blob/master/rnt/sample/sample.c)

[image]
Thank you

Comment: Showing the code that says what the command options are is not going to help anyone here help you with your problem.  You should post the code that is parsing the command line.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking us why your code is printing that you've passed invalid command line arguments? Because you should know that best. Or are you invoking `cl.exe` from command line and passing it paths to some JPG files?

Comment: @szczurcio its just D:\\ not the path , i changed it

Comment: Please use tags carefully?

Comment: One, don't you think you should show your command line parsing code? Two, "My Sequence is like E:\1.jpg D:\", Well the usage says the command line needs `-i` and `-o`, so are you actually passing those switches into the command line?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I added parsing code

Comment: `Invalid command line argument`. You claim that is the error yet your code never outputs that string. Are you showing all the code? Also, please show **exactly** the command line you are using.

Comment: I update the question

Comment: Please show **exactly** the command line you are using. Third time asking that. The command line you have shown does not have the `-i` and `-o` switches. It is not clear whether it is because you haven't shown that or whether you really are leaving those out.

Comment: Well clearly your command line is missing the `-i` and `-o` switches.

Comment: @kaylum -i and -o switches ? how to add them ?

Comment: `-i E:\\input.jpg -o E:\\output.jpg`

Comment: Can not read cascade from -i

Comment: Can not read cascade from -i ??? what is that supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

part of the problem is: argv[0] is the name of the program being executed.

argv[1] is the first command line argument (it should be either `-i` or `-o`) .

In general, Without using any of the command line short cut functions, like `getopt()`,

The first thing the code needs to do is make sure the required command line arguments exist.  (Per your posted code, argc needs to be 5)

then, in a loop, check if argv[x], (where `x`is either 1 or 3) is `-o` or `-i`.

Then, depending on the result of that check,

get argv[x+1] as either the input file or the output file.

Do all this checking in a loop

Doing the checking in a sequence, as the code is doing, is making a lot of assumptions about the order of the arguments and ignoring the checking to assure the arguments are valid.

I.E. never trust user input, always completely check it for validity

Suggest getting the code working correctly while only allowing single character arguments, then modify the code to allow `--longname` arguments